# Scala two tuples of list filter not working

Tags: scala

My two scala lists are as below. The two lists may have different lengths.

`val a = List((1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",5000), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",35357), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",43437), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",53), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",3306), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",22))`

and

`val b = List((1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",5000), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",35357), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",43437), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",53), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",3306), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",22))`

now I want to filter like this:

```
for { 
(a1,b1,c) <- a     
 (d,e,f)  <- b
if (b1!=e && c!=f)
} yield (d,e,f)
```

but when I execute above code it returns me as:

`List[(Long, String, Int)] = List((1437376639347,"192.168.1.8",45), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.3",34), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.13",90), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.1",34), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.5",45), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.10",56), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.22",344),(1437376639347,"192.168.1.10",56), (1437376639347,"192.168.1.22",344), (143737...`

The result mixes the tuples, and it returns wrong results. Actually the result should be the empty list because both lists of tuples contain the same data. If I check for `equals` like `if (b1==e && c==f)` it returns expected results but for `not equals` it mixes data.

Does anyone know the exact problem here? What I am missing?

**EDIT**

Another problem is that every time both lists not same check this new lists with less data .

`val a = List((1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",5000), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",35357), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",43437), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",53))`

and 
 `val b = List((1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",5000), (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.4",35357), (1437376639347L,"192.168.100.4",43437))`

and expected output as

`val result = List((1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",43437), (1437377239637L,"192.168.1.4",53),(1437376639347L,"192.168.100.4",43437))`

Basically I want to find out `two list of tuples set difference`

Comment: If you need empty result then you must use zip as chengpohi said. what you actually do is filter on cartesian set.

Comment: @Zernike problem is that my two lists not contains same length at every time .

Comment: @yogesh Then explain what result you want when the lists have different lengths.

Comment: @ChrisMartin I updated question please check

Comment: Can you please simplify the question? All of the values can be smaller/shorter to make the examples easier to read, the lists are longer than they need to be, and the third tuple element isn't necessary to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Trying testing with a simpler and smaller data set so it's easier to see what's going on.

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = a

for {
  a1 <- a
  b1 <- b
} yield (b1)

// Result: List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

You're mapping over the product of the two lists. It sounds like what you want instead is the zip of the lists.

```
for {
  (a1, b1) <- a zip b
} yield (a1, b1)

// Result: List((1,1), (2,2), (3,3))
```

Add back the filter, and we're done:

```
for {
  (a1, b1) <- a zip b
  if (a1 != b1)
} yield b1

// Result: List()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip your `a` and `b` list firstly and `loop` with condition:

```
for { 
  ((a1, b1, c), (d, e, f)) <- a zip b
  if (b1!=e && c!=f)
} yield (d,e,f)
```

Comment: I replaced some values in `list b` as `(1437376639347L,"192.168.20.1",45)` to `(1437376639347L,"192.168.1.100",45)` but still it returns empy lists

Comment: because `c!=f`, maybe `(1437376639347L,"192.168.20.1",45) to (1437376639347L,"192.168.1.100",42)`

Comment: got it your point but if both list different length then zip not working .